# A reference for existence/uniqueness theorem for an ODE with Carathéodory condition

Tags: functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, reference-request

Can anyone name good reference for proof of this version of existence theorem in ODE please. I'm tired of googling and finding nothing.

> $$\frac{du}{dt}=f(t,u(t))\qquad\text{for a.a. }t\in I, \qquad u(0)=u_0\tag{1.65}$$
>
> **Theorem 1.45.** (Existence and uniqueness) Let $T$ be fixed and $f \colon \mathbb I \times \mathbb R^k \to \mathbb R^k$ be a Carathéodory mapping satisfying the growth condition $|f(t,r)| \le \gamma(t)+C|r|$ with some $\gamma\in L^1(I)$. Then:
>
> - The initial value problem (1.65) has a solution $u\in W^{1,1}(I;\mathbb R^k)$ on the interval $I=[0,T]$.
> - If $f(t,\cdot)$ is also Lipschitz continuous in the sense $|f(t,r_1)-f(t,r_2)| \le \ell (t) |r_1-r_2|$ with some $\ell \in L^1(I)$, then the solution is unique.

Comment: Maybe you could have mentioned where this result is taken from. (Is it [Theorem 1.45](https://books.google.com/books?id=peZHAAAAQBAJ&pg=PA25) from Nonlinear Partial Differential Equations with Applications
 By Tomáš Roubíček?) If it is from some introductory chapter, where the authors collect some results needed later in the same text, do they say something about possible references there?

Comment: For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020), 
[here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559), 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1773) and 
[here](/help/notation). I have tried to retype the post from your picture. If needed, you can improve it and the images can then probably be removed from the post.

Comment: I am not sure to which extent it is going to be useful for you, but [a bit of googling](https://www.google.com/search?q=existence+uniqueness+caratheodory+mapping&tbm=bks) leads to Theorem 3.4 [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=ijjpCAAAQBAJ&pg=PA15), which looks rather similar to the second part of the claim from your post.

Comment: Thank you Martin for retyping my post, I am not professional in Latex but trying to be :). Yes, this theorem is from that book and no refrence is mentioned except usual huge bibliography in the end. Your link about similar theorem seems good and I'll read it. Thanks again.

Comment: Section I.5 in Hale's [textbook](http://www.amazon.com/Ordinary-Differential-Equations-Dover-Mathematics/dp/0486472116/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1444423742&sr=8-1&keywords=hale+ordinary) gives complete proof of this theorem.

Comment: Thank you Artem, It was 95% similar to my question.